# titanium TableRows are not inserted

Tags: titanium, tablerow, titanium-mobile

i'm getting a JSON response properly but my problem is with showing it. what's wrong with my code.

```
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
 Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

// create base UI tab and root window

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
title : 'Main Window',
backgroundColor : '#fff'
 }); 

 var listUrl = "http://magadhena.com/test/list.php?FCODE=5&USERID=1";
 var NumberOfLists = [];
 var lists;
 var tableData = [];
 var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
top : 40,
left : 10,
width : 300
});
var txt1 = Titanium.UI.createTextField({

top : 10,
left : 10,
width : 250

 });
 var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
top : 10,
left : 270,
width : 30

});

 var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setTimeout(3000);
xhr.onload = function() {
lists = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    var userId = lists[i].userid;
    // The userID
    var listId = lists[i].listid;
    // The ListID
    var listName = lists[i].listname;
    // The ListName

    var Object1 = new list(userId, listId, listName);

    // Ti.API.log("Object is ",Object1.listId);
    NumberOfLists.push(Object1);
    // Ti.API.log("the size of the Json array is" , NumberOfLists.length);
}
};
xhr.open("GET", listUrl);
xhr.send();

for(var i = 0; i < NumberOfLists.length; i++) {

var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title : NumberOfLists[i].listName
});
Ti.API.log("populating the data table ", NumberOfLists[i].toString);
tableData.push(row)

};

//  Ti.API.log("the size of table data is ", tableData.length);
table.setData(tableData);

win1.add(table);
win1.add(txt1);
win1.add(button1);

// Opening Window1

win1.open();

///// List Objects

function list(userid, listid, listname) {
this.userId = userid;
this.listId = listid;
this.listName = listname;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put table.setData() into xhr.onload function. Since you defined the code outside of the function, NumberOfLists is empty until xhr.onload function executed